# track the progress with ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

i am trying to communicate to web-service and to retrieve data, while doing that, i try to make progress indication with UIProgressView so that the user know what's going on, however, when i run, i don't see the progress on the UIProgressView.
here is my relevant code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //start request
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://iphone01.mtdgroup/admin_V01/stationsProcessing/pickers_management.php"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request=[ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setUploadProgressDelegate:loadingProgress];
    [request startAsynchronous];
    NSLog(@"value: %f",[loadingProgress progress]);
}
```

the log shows :  `value: 0.000000`.
According to the ASIHTTPRequest documentation, setting the `UIProgressView` as the delegate of the `uploadProgressDelegate` is sufficient and ASIHTTPRequest will take care of updating the UIProgressView for me.
am i missing something ? thx for advance :)

Answer (score 4):

You're doing an Asynchronous request so the NSLog executes immediately after the request is started at which point the progress would actually be zero - startAsynchronous actually uses an NSOperationQueue behind the scenes so you'll need to code your own delegate if you want to NSLog the progress:

just include something like this in your view controller:

```
- (void)setProgress:(float)newProgress {
   [loadingProgress setProgress:newProgress];
   NSLog(@"value: %f",[loadingProgress progress]);
}
```

and set:

```
[request setUploadProgressDelegate:self];
```

Comment: when this method will get called, is it called automatically ?

Comment: whenever the progress updates. btw, you should really hook up (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request delegate method so you can see if there is an error with the request after you start asynchronously.

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work, and in the log always same value `0.000000`

Comment: i have to mention that i use the `requestFailed` and the `requestFinished` methods to manage the request :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your class also conforms to the `ASIProgressDelegate` protocol.

```
@interface YourClass : ... <ASIHTTPRequestDelegate,ASIProgressDelegate>
```